# Banshee wrong Play Queue behavior

Tags: 10.10, banshee

It happens that when I put songs on the play queue and then they sound, the last song is not marked that already had sounded, and then (On shuffle mode) sounds a random song, and if I press to the next song, sounds the last one from play queue that never was marked as played, then the same thing, always play a random song and then the same song in the queue, this I manually mark it as played.

I'm using Banshee 1.8.0

Comment: This question was filed as a bug report, thanks!

Comment: @jrg Comma splices should be avoided.

Answer (score 2):

I can actually duplicate that same problem.  I just got finished with it myself using the same version.

Because it is not just you, I would suppose that either you or I need to file a bug report via Banshee's Bugzilla.

EDIT:  bugzilla filing [bug 632026](https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=632026)

Comment: I have filed a bug report on Bugzilla.

Comment: could you provide a link to this bug report?